# VB-SQL, Exception in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form3

```
Private cs As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HUSAIN-PC;Initial
```

Catalog=final1;Integrated Security=True")

```
Private da As New SqlDataAdapter
Private ds As New DataSet
Public dr As SqlDataReader
Public cmd As New SqlCommand
Private sql As String
Private sqlsel As String
Dim Bal As String
Dim id As String
Dim amt As String

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cs.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cs
    amt = TextBox2.Text
    id = TextBox1.Text
    sqlsel = "SELECT (Bal) FROM db5 WHERE Id='" + id + "'"
    da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlsel, cs)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        While (dr.Read())
            Bal = dr("Id")
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Balance is :" + Bal)

    Dim total As String = Bal + amt

    sql = "UPDATE db5 SET Bal='" + total + "' WHERE Id='" + id + "'"
    da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cs)
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("updated")
End Sub
```

End Class

This is my VB code to retrieve a value from the SQL DB...the Update statement is running fine bt wen i write the select i get an exception in the code:
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader
"ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized"

Comment: Aside from anything else, *please* don't build SQL like this. You're wide open for a SQL injection attack. Please use parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
sqlsel = "SELECT (Bal) FROM db5 WHERE Id='" + id + "'"
da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlsel, cs)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

You're specifying an `InsertCommand` as a SELECT query, but then you're calling `ExecuteReader` on a completely separate `SqlDataReader`... which hasn't got a query configured, as per the error message.

That's why you're getting this specific error, but there are *lots* of problems with this code:

- You should be creating a new `SqlConnection` / `SqlCommand` etc every time you want to execute a query
- You should be using `Using` statements to automatically close them
- You shouldn't have *instance* variables for these - they should be local variables
- I see no reason to use a `DataAdapter` here in the first place - just use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`
- **Very important**: You should be using parameterized SQL instead of including values directly in your SQL. See the [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) site for more information about this topic.

Comment: ill take all of dese into consideration...thnx a lot 4 ur help sir....just can u help me wat changes should be made to get dis piece of code running? i tried removing the statement "da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlsel, cs)" but still its not working....thnk u :)

Comment: @user997580: I've told you the changes you should be making. *Don't* just make minimal changes to get it working temporarily - fix the thing *properly*, following *all* of the steps above. Look at your code, work out what objects are involved. If you end up with code you can't understand, that won't actually help you at all.